# How to create a Mongoose Provider without schema. NestJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I need to create a mongoose connection to get db.stats(). I follow the nestjs tutorial to get data from database with mongoose and providers method. But I don´t get stats because this method create a relationship between mongoose and models.

I write this lines in my method, but the code is very acoplated:

```
async getStatsFromDatabase(): Promise<IDatabaseStats> {
  await mongoose.connect(env.base.mongodb.uri);
  const stats = await mongoose.connection.db.stats();
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  return stats;
}
```

how can get a connection with a provider without a mongoose schema?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I write the answer in case someone is interested:

Provider:

```
`const provider = {
    provide: config.health.providers.mongodb,
    useFactory: (connection: Connection): Connection => connection['connection'],
    inject: [env.providers.database.mongodb],
  },`
```

We should return connection.